# Group by both users and month in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, date, group-by, google-bigquery

I am very new to BigQuery and I have written the following query:

```
select
email,
min(address.zip) as zip,
min(country) as country,
min(source),
min(created_at) as first_order,
max(created_at)as last_order,
count(order_number) as number_orders,
sum(total_price) as total_spent
from orders_data
group by email
```

What it gives me is a table where all orders are grouped by customer with the following output:

```
email | zip | country | source | first_order | last_order | number_orders | total_spent |
```

What I would like to add is another **grouping by month**. I would like to have the total_spend and number_orders per customer (email) on a monthly basis.

Depending on what is easier, the results could either look like this:

```
email | zip | country | source | first_order | last_order | number_orders | total_spent | 2017_January_spent | 2017_January_num_orders | 2017_February_spent | 2017_February_num_orders | ... |
```

Or grouped by row and look like this:

```
 month  | email | zip | country | source | first_order | last_order | number_orders | total_spent | 2017_January_spent | 2017_January_num_orders | 2017_February_spent | 2017_February_num orders | ... | 
 01.2017| cust_A|
 02.2017| cust_A|
 03.2017| cust_A|
```

Not sure if it helps, but my data ranges from 2017 to 2020 and my timestamp variable "**created_at**" looks the following: **2020-01-02 16:20:12 UTC**

I have tried it by adding `group by moth(created_at)` and also played with `timestamp_trunc` but failed.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date_trunc()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc) or the appropriate function for your column type:

```
select timestamp_trunc(created_at, month) as mon, email,
       min(address.zip) as zip, min(country) as country, min(source),
       min(created_at) as first_order, max(created_at)as last_order,
       count(order_number) as number_orders, sum(total_price) as total_spent
from orders_data
group by mon, email
order by mon, email;
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your quick reply. I have tried the code, but unfortunately it gives me the following error:
No matching signature for function DATE_TRUNC for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: DATE_TRUNC(DATE, DATE_TIME_PART) at [2:1] - do you know what the issue could be?

Comment: @emil_rore . . . Then you want `timestamp_trunc()`.